# Continuous bounded function with specific properties

Tags: real-analysis

Is there any continuous function $f\colon \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ which is bounded and also increasing and for which lim$_{x\rightarrow \infty}$ f(x) exists.

So far I only have $\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)$, $e^{-1/x}$ as examples of bounded continuous functions which dont satisfy above properties

Comment: Basically all: every increasing, bounded from above function $f$ on an interval $[a,\infty)$ has a limit at $\infty$.

Comment: Visually, you're just looking for increasing functions with two horizontal asymptopes

Answer (score 3):

A great example of this is $f(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{x}$.  The function is increasing.  And as $x\rightarrow\infty, f(x)\rightarrow 1$.

Answer (score 1):

There are many. If you want one given by a formula, you can use $\arctan x$.

Comment: Please give a few more

Comment: What about $\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$ for $x\ge 0$, and $-\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$ for $x\lt 0$? For there to be a reason to produce more, there would need to be additional conditions required of the function, conditions that the two examples you now have, or their close relatives, do not meet.

Comment: You are welcome.